# how to load extensions in sqlite3?

Tags: c, visual-studio, sqlite

I'm trying to load regexp.c extension in order to add REGEXP operator into sqlite. What I have done:

1. Download sqlite3 amalgamation file
2. Found [regexp.c loadable extension](https://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact/a68d25c659bd2d89)
3. Created test project in VS2015

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include "sqlite3.h"

   const char* SQL = "SELECT load_extension('sqlite3.obj', 'sqlite3_regexp_init');";

   int main(int argc, char **argv) {

       sqlite3 *db = 0; // the hande of connection object to db
       char *err = 0;
       char *errMsg = "unable to load extension";

       // open connection
       if (sqlite3_open("my_cosy_database.dblite", &db))
           fprintf(stderr, "Error during opening/creation DB: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
       /*else if (sqlite3_db_config(db, SQLITE_DBCONFIG_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION, 1, 0))
       {
           fprintf(stderr, "Cannot enable extensions loading: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
       }*/
       else if (sqlite3_enable_load_extension(db, 1))
       {
           fprintf(stderr, "Cannot enable extensions loading: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
       }
       // execute SQL
       else if (sqlite3_load_extension(db, "sqlite3.obj", "sqlite3_regexp_init", &errMsg))
       {
           fprintf(stderr, "Cannot load sqlite3_regexp_init extension: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
       }
       else if (sqlite3_exec(db, SQL, callback, 0, &err))
       {
           fprintf(stderr, "Ошибка SQL: %sn", err);
           sqlite3_free(err);
       }
       // close connection
       sqlite3_close(db);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

[Official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html) says: "For security reasons, extension loading is turned off by default. In order to use either the C-language or SQL extension loading functions, one must first enable extension loading using the sqlite3_db_config(db,SQLITE_DBCONFIG_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION,1,NULL) C-language API in your application." So this is what I've done. The problem is that I got [image: this terrible error] every time sqlite3_load_extension or sqlite3_exec is called. The same problem appears with commented sqlite3_enable_load_extension and uncommented sqlite3_db_config. I have no idea what causes this exception and there is no clear example of C api usage (even in 'Using Sqlite' book). One thing i could find out is the statement which causes this exception: "(*pCtx->pFunc->xSFunc)(pCtx, pCtx->argc, pCtx->argv);/* IMP: R-24505-23230 */" in the SQLITE_PRIVATE int sqlite3VdbeExec(Vdbe *p /* The VDBE */).

So please, help.

Comment: Did you compile the extension correctly (How?)

Comment: I've inserted source code into amalgamation file and built it with vs

Comment: When you compile the extension correctly, you get a .DLL file.

Comment: CL. Yeah, but sample select query instead of load_extension works fine..

Comment: @cl, finally it is turned out that you were right. I've compiled .dll in other project and placed it in my test project. And it works. Thank you for a tip. I'd like to mark your comment as answer if I could

Comment: I don't use VS; only you know how you did it.